# Firewall as a guest VM?

Tags: virtualization, performance, firewall, scaling

Out of curiosity, would it be pointless/wasteful/silly to put a firewall as a VM guest (regardless of VM host - ESX, Xen, Hyper-V, etc. etc.) and redirect all traffic from other VM guests through the firewall VM guest?

I'm not sure if other people/organizations practice this or not. I know resources might be constrained (CPU, RAM, Disk/Net I/O) pending whatever traffic may pass, but are there any other scenarios or situations where placing a firewall as a guest VM and having the other guest VMs route to it rather is *better* or *comparable* to an external box from the host VM?

In terms of performance, I realize that being a guest VM resource usage will affect other guests but aside from that, am I missing anything? Security, best practices, common sense?

Any thoughts, comments or criticisms are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common configuration often called "DMZ in a box". [Here's a VMware whitepaper](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/dmz_virtualization_vmware_infra_wp.pdf) that discusses the various levels of collapsing DMZs using virtual infrastructure.

VMware's vSphere builds on some of these ideas and extends them with a product called [vShield Zones](http://www.vmware.com/products/vshield-zones/)

Comment: I wasn't aware that this was a feature within vSphere. Very cool! Thanks for the links.

Comment: Worth additional emphasis: For this to provide *ANY* security your VM traffic net and your VMWare Management net need to be physically separate.

Comment: @voretaq7 - absolutely.